# Same instances between tests

Tags: integration-testing, spring-test, spring-boot-test

I wrote two test(I mean different classes) that is configured with this annotations:

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest

When I run them solitary - everything is Ok
Magic happens when I run them simultaneously using 'test' task from gradle. One test creates an instance and then, somehow, transfer it to another class.
Has anyone ever met smth like this?

Comment: If you are talking about the ApplicationContext  (what you call "instance"): this is the default behaviour with Spring Test: ApplicationContext is reused between tests. see more details in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44181188/6899896

Comment: @M.Ricciuti, thanks. Didn't know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@DirtiesContext` to tell that a test class will be modifying the ApplicationContext. Therefore any other subsequent test class will not pick up that modification

```
@DirtiesContext
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```